# Combine flags and clear back trace in kotlin

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, backtrace

I am using Kotlin to develop an android application. In Android, we were using addFlags and setFlags to set flags and clear the backtrace activities separated by "|". How to achieve it in Kotlin? I am currently using below code in Kotlin:

```
startActivity(Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
```

But it is not Working. I have also tried addFlags, It is also not working. What should be done in this scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use it like this

```
val intent = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)                
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Comment: @SirajSumra are you using `android:launchMode` modifications?

Comment: Yes android:launchmode=singleTop

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK worked perfectly and not Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Will it make any issues?

Comment: This in not issue, please check explanation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 2):

```
 val intent = Intent(activity!!, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    activity!!.finishAffinity()
```

Answer (score 2):

use this with intent in order to clear the backtrace activities

```
var intent = Intent(this, [Your_activity]:class.java)
    intent.flags =  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val intent = Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
startActivity(intent)
```

add to Manifest `android:launchMode="singleTask`

Answer (score 0):

use this with intent in order to clear the backtrace activities

> **Java**

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

> **Kotlin**

```
 var intent = Intent(this, [Your_activity]:class.java)
        intent.flags =  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
```